# How to ignore words in sentences word cloud Python

Tags: python, stop-words, word-cloud

I am trying to create word cloud from a column and I want to ignore few words from the column. Data as shown below

```
       comments
I have a 2019 DVD, Tech package
So I went to dealership today to pick up cds. 
Have 2019 Lariat following and hope you get this going.
Curious to this as well.  
Still working on it guys. 
I have a something
Quote: Originally Posted by sigspec I have a 2019 with all features
Quote: Originally Posted by KR2019 you should have eveerything
Quote: Originally Posted by RockWVU So what all does he need then?
```

my code is as below

```
def plot_wordcloud(text, mask=None, max_words=400, max_font_size=120, figure_size=(24.0,16.0), 
                   title = None, title_size=40, image_color=False):
    stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
    more_stopwords = {'Quote','Originally posted'}
    stopwords = stopwords.union(more_stopwords)
def show_wordcloud(data, title = None):
    wordcloud = WordCloud(
        background_color='white',
        stopwords=stopwords,
        max_words=200,
        max_font_size=40, 
        scale=3,
        random_state=1 # chosen at random by flipping a coin; it was heads
    ).generate(str(data))

    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(12, 12))
    plt.axis('off')
    if title: 
        fig.suptitle(title, fontsize=20)
        fig.subplots_adjust(top=2.3)

    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.show()

show_wordcloud(df['Comments'])
```

Even after using stop words the words still appear in the cloud. How can I ignore these words.

Comment: Maybe put `stopwords = stopwords.union(more_stopwords)` etc. at the start of function `show_wordcloud`? In the above code it is never executed. Moreover, using global variables might make it hard to track bugs.

Comment: It still gives me the same result

Comment: And also add the words separately to `more_stopwords = {'Quote','Originally','posted'}`

Comment: Are you sure `stopwords` is initialized at the time of calling the `WordCloud`-constructor? Either you've omitted quite a bit of code here, or you've left several variables uninitialized. Check with a debugger.

Comment: I havenot omitted any code

Comment: In that case it's very you have some undefined variables. `plot_wordcloud` isn't being called, thus `stopwords` isn't getting defined. `plt` seems to be undefined, too. Just weird that you actually seem to get some output, for me it just always fails before entering into the function because `df` isn't defined, too.